# Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-redux'.

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Got an issue with typescript and react + redux

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-redux'. '/home/andrew/miramir/src/js/node_modules/react-redux/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Trying to get Provider from react-redux

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
```

How i can fix it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You should just add the needed types to your project, like this:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/react-redux
```

Comment: or `yarn add @types/react-redux --dev`

Comment: Very interesting. Previously, I didn't need to install this specific package in a .ts React project to use `react-redux`. The issue occurred very randomly at the latest project. Very weird indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with

```
const { Provider } = require('react-redux');
```

Comment: it is same as import {Provider} from "react-redux"

Comment: @KhalidAzam If you use require(), you're not required to have a declaration file.  This isn't intentional; require() was the old way of loading modules and import is the new way.

Answer (score 0):

For yarn

```
yarn add --dev @types/react-redux
```